# Most succinct way to count common values across multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a medical database table having hundreds of thousands of records (patients), where each record has six "condition" fields (condition1, condition2, ...) specifying one or more chronic medical conditions for which the patient has been diagnosed. All patients will have at least one condition and optionally up to six conditions specified. What I am now trying to do is put together a list of the top 10 conditions (out of possibly 30 distinct conditions) associated with this patient population but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how best to enumerate all of the conditions found across six record columns. While I can think of several brute force approaches, I strongly suspect there are one or more powerful combinations of SQL expressions that are well-suited for this kind of thing. While I considerable myself a competent coder, I am by no means a SQL expert and I defer to others who have considerably more depth in this domain. Suggestions?

FWIW, I have tried issuing queries to identify all of the different condition types found in the table across all six columns. From there, I was going to query each condition found to come up with a count for each. While this seems workable, I suspect some combination of the SQL DISTINCT and UNIQUE terms (or perhaps a UNION of columns?) would make this task much easier but I haven't yet found a use case on the web that quite matches what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Note that tables have _rows_ and _columns_, not records or fields.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: FWIW, I would recommend changing the table format to a tall layout. So your columns might be RECORD_ID, CONDITION_CODE and SEQUENCE. Then your 6 conditions can be sequenced 1 through 6 in that sequence column. Some records might have just one row, some might have 6 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unpivot the table. Then counting is easy.

For example:

```
select cond, count(*)
from (
  select condition1 as cond from t
  union all select condition2 from t
  union all select condition3 from t
  union all select condition4 from t
  union all select condition5 from t
  union all select condition6 from t
) x
group by cond
order by count(*) desc
```